# Can I customize a Dynamics AX field in list page grid with a query that does a calculation?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Looking to customize an AX2012 list page grid view column for users that would query and return: open transactions amount short paid on the All Customers list page grid. Is this possible using the add fields feature and entering a query within system name?

Comment: Could you describe or show us what you have tried so far? Please [edit] new information into your question instead of giving it in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve that requirement by using the `Add fields` feature from the `Personalisation` form.

You would need to create (develop) a new display method in the Customers (`CustTable`) table (if it hasn't been created already) and add that display method to the `CustTableListPage` form in the `Application Object Tree`.

This is a development task, not a personalisation.